# Issues with trying to find if class has changed in-between frames

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list of a custom class. Every frame I want to find if any of the classes are new or modified since the last frame and change some of their properties if they are.

This is what I originally thought was the best way of doing this

```
public List<Custom> currList;
List<Custom> lastFrameList;

void Update()
{
    if (lastFrameList != null)
    {
            foreach (Custom c in currList)
            {
                if (!lastFrameList.Contains(c)
                {
                    DoStuff()
                }
            }
     }
     lastFrameList = currList;
}
```

But this never reaches the method. I have also tried using Find() Equals() Any() and putting this in OnValidate(). The class has a lot of stuff in it including an enum array. I'm currently mostly testing runtime editor changes.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: are you missing `lastFrameList = new List<Custom>()` ? because then the first `if` would not run. edit: Hmm but it would get assigned after that (to currList). However the first "change" would not be found.

Comment: Thats a good point @KYL3R . But it doesnt need to run on the first frame anyway because it's impossible for there to be a change before then that isnt setting the initial values,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
lastFrameList = currList
```

try out

```
lastFrameList = currList.toList()
```

This will create a copy of currList instead of pointing directly to currList.

All changes in currList will be in lastFrameList with your code so this is the reason lastFrameList never missing a Custom.

Edit (Detected that a Custom Object has changed):

In your custom class you could do something like this:

```
public bool Attributes_changed { get;set;}
private int m_someAttribute;
public int SomeAttribute {
 get
 {
   return m_someAttribute;
 }
 set
 {
    Attributes_changed = true;
    m_someAttribute = value;
 }
}

public Custom(//your parameters){
     Attributes_changed = false;
}
```

so now al the time you set the attribute (SomeAttribute=2 for example) your flag will be set to true. Then in your update function you could check for it:

```
void Update()
{
    if (lastFrameList != null)
    {
        foreach (Custom c in currList)
        {
            if (!lastFrameList.Contains(c))
            {
                //Do stuff for a newly added custom object
                DoStuff()
            }
            if (c.Attributes_changed){
                //Do stuff for changed attributes.
                DoStuff()
                c.Attributes_changed = false;
            }
        }
     }
     lastFrameList = currList.toList();
}
```

if you want to do the same thing in both cases you could combine the two if statements.

Comment: How do you add things to your currList? It could be a good idea, like Daveloper mentioned, to look at the count of both lists, when you are inside the first if statement, or to set breakpoints and look at the lists manually, to see if they differ like you want them to.

Comment: they are exactly the same at all times like u expected. I do all modifications through the unity editor.

Comment: So just to be clear. You add a new object to your currList through the unity editor and are not editing a existing one?

Comment: i would like the script to handle both but right now im just editing an existing one

Comment: Ok so you are editing a existing custom? That explains, why the count does not change. So like Daveloper wrote, lastFrameList does contain the custom you edited, so the contains method returns true.

Comment: A simple solution could be to add a bool flag to your custom class, that is set to be true, if you changed something. In your update function you could check that flag, do your stuff and set it back to false. This would work if you just want to do something regardless of which attribute of custom changed

Comment: Is there a way to do this automatically, as in not having to set the bool myself.

Comment: Or maybe something other than ToList() i can try?

Comment: There is nothing a second list can help you if there are always the same elements in it. I will edit my post for a simple solution for the flag.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I really liked the flag solution, but unfortunately it didnt help. Unity can't serialize properties easily, so to allow for editor changing I would have to make the private variable serialized which would defeat the whole purpose of the property. I solved it by having the old values stored within the class and using ToArray(). Not sure why that worked but toList() didnt but tbh I dont care anymore. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

A few things here:
1) what part of the code is never reached? try

```
public List<Custom> currList;
List<Custom> lastFrameList;

void Update()
{
    if (lastFrameList != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("lastFrameList is not null");
        foreach (Custom c in currList)
        {
            if (!lastFrameList.Contains(c))
            {
                Debug.Log("there is a new element in currList that was not there in lastFrameList");
                DoStuff()
            }
         }
     }
     lastFrameList = currList;
}
```

If it never reaches the first log, then your currList is never initialised.
If it just never reaches the second log, then your list either never has new entries, or you forget to add them to the list.

2) Also important: your Custom class instances in the list are references. If attributes change, the elements in your list are still the same references! So "lastFrameList.Contains(c)" will evaluate to true, by the way there is a bracket missing there...

If you want to compare the attributes inside your class instances in order to decide wether or not the class instances changed their attributes, you'll need to either implement a function

```
public class Custom
{

    // ... your class

    public bool Equals(Custom other)
    {
        return (attr1 == other.attr1) && (attr2 == other.attr2) && ... ;
    }
}
```

or make it a struct, but this would have a bunch of other consequences

3) As stated by René Kling, the List it-self is also just a reference, so you are not doing a copy with "lastFrameList = currList;", Meaning if after this statement you change currList, that will propagate to queries on lastFrameList, because it references the same List.

Comment: 1) i did debug before asking this question (i really dont like posting to SO unless i really have to). it reached the first statement but never the second. im not really sure how point 2 and 3 are different but i get the point. thanks for the help